# How to create a document on a sharepoint using C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library, file

I know how to create a word document using c#.

The issue I am having is I don't know how to place that document in the SharePoint folder.

```
var newfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Documents", "filename" + ".docx");

System.IO.File.Create(newfile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [Open XML SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) to create Office documents, then using SharePoint client object model File.SaveBinaryDirect Method to upload the document to folder in SharePoint library.

**Example code:**

```
string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";
var login = "lz@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "xxx";
var documentLibrary = "DL0627";
var folderUrl = "/sites/lz/"+documentLibrary+"/folder1/";
var fileName = "test1.docx";

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //1. Create Document
    using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
    {
        document.AddMainDocumentPart();
        document.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(new Body(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Some content goes here")))));
    }

    //2. Upload file into a SharePoint Library folder 
    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
    {
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
        var targetFileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", folderUrl, fileName);
        stream.Position = 0;
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, targetFileUrl, stream, true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can upload documents to SharePoint libraries using the Object Model or [SharePoint Webservices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.aspx).

Upload using Object Model:

```
String fileToUpload = @"C:\YourFile.txt";
String sharePointSite = "http://yoursite.com/sites/Research/";
String documentLibraryName = "Shared Documents";

using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);                    

        SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

        // Prepare to upload
        Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
        String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

        // Upload document
        SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

        // Commit 
        myLibrary.Update();
    }
}
```

**Reference**:

1. [How do you upload a file to a document library in sharepoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint).
2. [C# code to upload document to SharePoint](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/602369/C-23pluscodeplustoplusuploadplusdocumentplustoplus).
3. [Upload A Document To A SharePoint 2013 Library Using Client Side Object Model](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/upload-a-document-to-a-sharepoint-2013-library-using-client/).

Comment: I am using .net Core MVC missing names space for "SPSite," SPFile and SPWeb already reference Microsoft.SharePoint.Client dll and Microsoft.SharePoint dll

Comment: Check this [solution](http://blog.vitalyzhukov.ru/en/CSOM-अपलोड-document), how to use CSOM to upload document in SharePoint library.